# Nested conditions not returning any results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreign-keys, relational-database, datamapper

We are creating an AirBnB clone as part of a course. To do this, we have created linked tables using DataMapper

```rb
class User
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id,          Serial
  property :email,       String,  :required => true,
                                  :unique => true,
                                  :format => :email_address
  property :password,    String, :required => true

  has n, :spaces
  has n, :bookings

end
```

```rb
class Space
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id,          Serial
  property :name,        String,  required: true
  property :description, Text,    required: true
  property :price,       Integer, required: true
  property :checkin,     Date,    required: true
  property :checkout,    Date,    required: true

  belongs_to :user
  has n, :bookings

end
```

```rb
class Booking
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id,           Serial
  property :arrival,      Date,     required: true
  property :departure,    Date,     required: true
  property :confirmed,    Boolean

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :space

end
```

We are trying to get all unconfirmed (`null`) bookings on for spaces which are created by a specific user-id.

Based on the [datamapper documentation](https://datamapper.org/docs/find.html) on Nested Conditions, we have tried the following with the foreign keys:

```rb
user = session[:user]
bookings = {:confirmed => nil, :space_id => { :user_id => user.id } }
p Booking.all(bookings)
```

Which according to the documentation should return the correct details, but instead returns an empty array.

Could anyone suggest how to nest the conditions correctly

Comment: I think this `bookings = {:confirmed => nil, :space_id => { :user_id => user.id } }` should be `bookings = {:confirmed => nil, :space => { :user_id => user.id } }`(singular). I don't use datamapper but the documentation seems to suggest this is how it would be accomplished.

Comment: We ended up reformatting to `bookings = Booking.all({Booking.space.user.id => user.id})`, but I think that comes down to a similar solution that we should have been using `space` rather than `space_id`!